this EXE was compiles for the x64 architecture
I developed a Flutter application and used Inno Setup to create an installer for it. The installer seems to work fine, and the installation process completes without any issues. However, when I try to run the installed application, I encounter the following error message:
"This EXE was compiles for the x64 architecture."
Below is the debug log which i could see when installing and running the application in inno setup script
[18:19:09.139]   *** Setup started
[18:19:11.082]   Setup version: Inno Setup version 6.3.3
[18:19:11.083]   Original Setup EXE: C:\Users\Admin\Documents\flutterApps\prod_view\installer1\Prod View.exe
[18:19:11.083]   Setup command line: /SL5="$70652,9961525,969728,C:\Users\Admin\Documents\flutterApps\prod_view\installer1\Prod View.exe" /SPAWNWND=$6060A /NOTIFYWND=$A054E /DEBUGWND=$20520 
[18:19:11.084]   Windows version: 10.0.19045
[18:19:11.084]   Windows architecture: x64 (64-bit)
[18:19:11.085]   Machine types supported by system: x86 x64
[18:19:11.085]   User privileges: Administrative
[18:19:11.087]   Administrative install mode: Yes
[18:19:11.088]   Install mode root key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
[18:19:11.089]   64-bit install mode: Yes
[18:19:11.090]   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\is-HREAD.tmp
[18:20:30.591]   Found 5 files to register with RestartManager.
[18:20:30.592]   Calling RestartManager's RmGetList.
[18:20:30.718]   RmGetList finished successfully.
[18:20:30.719]   RestartManager found no applications using one of our files.
[18:20:30.727]   Starting the installation process.
[18:20:30.731]   Directory for uninstall files: C:\Program Files\Prod Viewer
[18:20:30.737]   Will append to existing uninstall log: C:\Program Files\Prod Viewer\unins000.dat
[18:20:30.739]   -- File entry --
[18:20:30.740]   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\Prod Viewer\unins000.exe
[18:20:30.741]   Non-default bitness: 32-bit
[18:20:30.743]   Time stamp of our file: 2024-09-15 18:19:10.955
[18:20:30.744]   Dest file exists.
[18:20:30.745]   Time stamp of existing file: 2024-09-15 18:02:03.936
[18:20:30.745]   Version of our file: 51.1052.0.0
[18:20:30.792]   Version of existing file: 51.1052.0.0
[18:20:30.793]   Installing the file.
[18:20:30.798]   Leaving temporary file in place for now.
[18:20:30.802]   -- File entry --
[18:20:30.803]   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\Prod Viewer\MyProg-x64.exe
[18:20:30.804]   Time stamp of our file: 2024-06-24 05:30:00.000
[18:20:30.805]   Dest file exists.
[18:20:30.806]   Time stamp of existing file: 2024-06-24 05:30:00.000
[18:20:30.807]   Installing the file.
[18:20:30.811]   Successfully installed the file.
[18:20:30.814]   -- File entry --
[18:20:30.815]   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\Prod Viewer\prod_view.exe
[18:20:30.816]   Time stamp of our file: 2024-09-15 17:29:46.000
[18:20:30.817]   Dest file exists.
[18:20:30.818]   Time stamp of existing file: 2024-09-15 17:29:46.000
[18:20:30.818]   Installing the file.
[18:20:30.822]   Successfully installed the file.
[18:20:30.825]   -- File entry --
[18:20:30.826]   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\Prod Viewer\file_selector_windows_plugin.dll
[18:20:30.827]   Time stamp of our file: 2024-09-14 16:35:52.000
[18:20:30.828]   Dest file exists.
[18:20:30.829]   Time stamp of existing file: 2024-09-14 16:35:52.000
[18:20:30.830]   Installing the file.
[18:20:30.834]   Successfully installed the file.
[18:20:30.836]   -- File entry --
[18:20:30.838]   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\Prod Viewer\flutter_windows.dll
[18:20:30.839]   Time stamp of our file: 2024-07-28 21:05:34.000
[18:20:30.840]   Dest file exists.
[18:20:30.841]   Time stamp of existing file: 2024-07-28 21:05:34.000
[18:20:30.841]   Installing the file.
[18:20:31.220]   Successfully installed the file.
[18:20:31.223]   -- File entry --
[18:20:31.224]   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\Prod Viewer\sqlite3.dll
[18:20:31.225]   Time stamp of our file: 2024-08-13 16:42:36.000
[18:20:31.226]   Dest file exists.
[18:20:31.227]   Time stamp of existing file: 2024-08-13 16:42:36.000
[18:20:31.228]   Installing the file.
[18:20:31.292]   Successfully installed the file.
[18:20:31.295]   -- File entry --
[18:20:31.296]   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\Prod Viewer\data\app.so
[18:20:31.297]   Time stamp of our file: 2024-09-14 16:40:38.000
[18:20:31.298]   Dest file exists.
[18:20:31.299]   Time stamp of existing file: 2024-09-14 16:40:38.000
[18:20:31.300]   Installing the file.
[18:20:31.408]   Successfully installed the file.
[18:20:31.411]   -- File entry --
[18:20:31.412]   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\Prod Viewer\data\icudtl.dat
[18:20:31.414]   Time stamp of our file: 2024-07-28 21:04:28.000
[18:20:31.414]   Dest file exists.
[18:20:31.415]   Time stamp of existing file: 2024-07-28 21:04:28.000
[18:20:31.416]   Installing the file.
[18:20:31.443]   Successfully installed the file.
[18:20:31.445]   -- File entry --
[18:20:31.446]   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\Prod Viewer\data\flutter_assets\AssetManifest.bin
[18:20:31.447]   Time stamp of our file: 2024-09-14 16:40:38.000
[18:20:31.448]   Dest file exists.
[18:20:31.449]   Time stamp of existing file: 2024-09-14 16:40:38.000
[18:20:31.450]   Installing the file.
[18:20:31.451]   Successfully installed the file.
[18:20:31.452]   -- File entry --
[18:20:31.453]   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\Prod Viewer\data\flutter_assets\AssetManifest.json
[18:20:31.455]   Time stamp of our file: 2024-09-14 16:40:38.000
[18:20:31.455]   Dest file exists.
[18:20:31.456]   Time stamp of existing file: 2024-09-14 16:40:38.000
[18:20:31.457]   Installing the file.
[18:20:31.459]   Successfully installed the file.
[18:20:31.460]   -- File entry --
[18:20:31.461]   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\Prod Viewer\data\flutter_assets\FontManifest.json
[18:20:31.462]   Time stamp of our file: 2024-09-14 16:40:38.000
[18:20:31.463]   Dest file exists.
[18:20:31.464]   Time stamp of existing file: 2024-09-14 16:40:38.000
[18:20:31.465]   Installing the file.
[18:20:31.466]   Successfully installed the file.
[18:20:31.468]   -- File entry --
[18:20:31.469]   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\Prod Viewer\data\flutter_assets\NOTICES.Z
[18:20:31.470]   Time stamp of our file: 2024-09-14 16:40:38.000
[18:20:31.471]   Dest file exists.
[18:20:31.472]   Time stamp of existing file: 2024-09-14 16:40:38.000
[18:20:31.473]   Installing the file.
[18:20:31.479]   Successfully installed the file.
[18:20:31.481]   -- File entry --
[18:20:31.482]   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\Prod Viewer\data\flutter_assets\assets\images\bgImage.png
[18:20:31.483]   Time stamp of our file: 2024-09-12 21:08:30.000
[18:20:31.484]   Dest file exists.
[18:20:31.484]   Time stamp of existing file: 2024-09-12 21:08:30.000
[18:20:31.485]   Installing the file.
[18:20:31.487]   Successfully installed the file.
[18:20:31.491]   -- File entry --
[18:20:31.492]   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\Prod Viewer\data\flutter_assets\fonts\MaterialIcons-Regular.otf
[18:20:31.493]   Time stamp of our file: 2024-07-28 21:04:10.000
[18:20:31.494]   Dest file exists.
[18:20:31.495]   Time stamp of existing file: 2024-07-28 21:04:10.000
[18:20:31.495]   Installing the file.
[18:20:31.527]   Successfully installed the file.
[18:20:31.529]   -- File entry --
[18:20:31.530]   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\Prod Viewer\data\flutter_assets\packages\cupertino_icons\assets\CupertinoIcons.ttf
[18:20:31.531]   Time stamp of our file: 2024-07-27 11:52:06.000
[18:20:31.532]   Dest file exists.
[18:20:31.533]   Time stamp of existing file: 2024-07-27 11:52:06.000
[18:20:31.534]   Installing the file.
[18:20:31.543]   Successfully installed the file.
[18:20:31.544]   -- File entry --
[18:20:31.545]   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\Prod Viewer\data\flutter_assets\shaders\ink_sparkle.frag
[18:20:31.546]   Time stamp of our file: 2024-09-14 16:40:38.000
[18:20:31.547]   Dest file exists.
[18:20:31.547]   Time stamp of existing file: 2024-09-14 16:40:38.000
[18:20:31.548]   Installing the file.
[18:20:31.550]   Successfully installed the file.
[18:20:31.553]   -- Icon entry --
[18:20:31.554]   Dest filename: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Prod Viewer.lnk
[18:20:31.556]   Creating the icon.
[18:20:31.588]   Successfully created the icon.
[18:20:31.597]   -- Icon entry --
[18:20:31.599]   Dest filename: C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Prod Viewer.lnk
[18:20:31.600]   Creating the icon.
[18:20:31.602]   Successfully created the icon.
[18:20:31.612]   Saving uninstall information.
[18:20:31.613]   Renaming uninstaller.
[18:20:31.615]   Deleting uninstall key left over from previous administrative 64-bit install.
[18:20:31.617]   Creating new uninstall key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{64B091DE-4455-4E23-9F69-322DD4F0BEA6}_is1
[18:20:31.619]   Writing uninstall key values.
[18:20:31.623]   Detected previous non administrative install? No
[18:20:31.625]   Detected previous administrative 32-bit install? No
[18:20:31.630]   Installation process succeeded.
[18:20:31.632]   Need to restart Windows? No
[18:20:38.227]   -- Run entry --
[18:20:38.228]   Run as: Original user
[18:20:38.229]   Type: Exec
[18:20:38.230]   Filename: C:\Program Files\Prod Viewer\MyProg-x64.exe
[18:20:38.267]   Deinitializing Setup.
[18:20:38.309]   *** Setup exit code: 0

I am new to windows desktop application, not aware of installer and stuff. Any help will be helpful.
Thanks in advance

Are you trying to run it on a 32-bit system?  Flutter does not support targeting 32-bit Windows platforms.

I resolved the issue. I was installing it in C:\ProgramFiles. installing it in any other directory resolve the issue
